# How could I downgrade the IOS7 to 6.1.3?

Tags: ipad, ios7, downgrade

I upgraded my Ipad4 to ios7 few days ago,but it`s very slow .Is it possible to downgrade to  6.1.3.Thanks.

Comment: if you are doing backups you can restore via itunes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/507817/20130921/ios7-gm-downgrade-ios6-iphone-ipad-ipodtouch5.htm

if you are doing backups you can restore via itunes